# How to make a loop over all keys of a HashMap?

Tags: java, loops, iterator, hashmap

I try to do it in the following way:

```
public String getValue(String service, String parameter) {
    String inputKey = service + ":" + parameter;
    Set keys = name2value.keySet();
    Iterator itr = keys.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {     
        if (inputKey.equal(itr.next())) {
            return name2value.get(inputKey);
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

And I get an error message: cannot find symbol method.equal(java.lang.Object).

I think it is because itr.next() is not considered as a string. How can I solve this problem? I tried to replace `Set keys` by `Set<String> keys`. It did not help.

Comment: Why the downvote?  This is a legitimate, specific and well-written question.  Downvoting questions just for being beginner questions will scare new users away.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method you want is called `equals` not `equal`.

However there are a few other flaws in your code.

Firstly you should not be looping through all keys in a `Map` to find a specific key, just use `get` and/or `containsKey`.

The second `return` is also wrong.  It will return `""` if the *first* key does not match.  If you want to return `""` when *none* of the keys match, the `return` should go at the end of the method e.g.:

```
public String getValue(String service, String parameter) {
    String inputKey = service + ":" + parameter;
    String value = name2value.get(inputKey);
    if (value == null) {
        return "";
    } else {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstoff,The method is equals()
Secondly, cast `itr.next()` to string instead of Set.